# About the standard Laplace distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I want to calculate the mean absolute deviation from
the median and the interquartile range of the standard Laplace distribution

$f\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{2}e^{-\left|x\right|}\:,\:x\:\in \mathbb{R}$

I already know that the interquartile range is obtained from the CDF

$F(x) = \begin{cases} 
     \frac{1}{2}e^x & x< 0 \\
      1-\frac{1}{2}e^x & x\ge 0 \\ 
   \end{cases}$

$IQR=2\ln(2)$

For the mean absolute deviation from
the median is where I got stuck.

Sorry if the question is too basic I'm just a beginner hehe, learning by self-studying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly compute the mean absolute deviation from the median in the following way
$$
\text{Mean absolute deviation from the median}=\int|x-0|\frac{1}{2}e^{-\left|x\right|}\, dx=2\int_{x\geq 0}x\frac{1}{2}e^{-x}\, dx \\=\Gamma{(1)}=1.
$$

So why your answer is different?

[Median absolute deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_absolute_deviation) is a different quantity than the [mean absolute deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average_absolute_deviation) from the median. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! yes it really helps. what you are showing me there is the MAD (median absolute deviation) directly from it's definition right.  For the mean absolute deviation from the median how it would be compute it?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, what I showed is that directly computing mean absolute deviation from the median from the definition. You got the right answer for median absolute deviation. I have edited the answer. Best

Comment: Ok ok, I see thanks!